# Failed to get location of Visual Studio from registry

Tags: exception, visual-studio-2012, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 to create a CRM 2011 Workflow Project

After filling the details of the CRM server I get this message

"failed to get location of Visual Studio from registry"

Why? and How to fix it please.

Answer (score 0):

if you're on a 64 bit machine, try copying the whole visual studio registry key from local_machine to current_user.

Comment: I exported the visual studio keys edited the .reg file so that they would import to current user. didn't change the error.